# Sphinx Search and custom rank based on shortest word occurrence - how to?

Tags: search, sphinx, ranking

For example, the search query is "rank" and there is few results:

```
Row #1: ranking good
Row #2: rank greater
Row #3: my custom rank
```

But would like

```
Row #1: rank greater
Row #2: ranking good
Row #3: my custom rank
```

I using

```
expr('sum((10*(101-IF(min_hit_pos<100,min_hit_pos,100))+exact_hit)*user_weight)*1000+bm25')
```

Another way with LCS is not optimal for me, because there is a blend_chars and "multi-part" takes more weight then "multi" or "part" separately

```
expr('sum((4*lcs+(101-IF(min_hit_pos<100,min_hit_pos,100))+exact_hit)*user_weight)*1000+bm25')
```

Sphinx 2.1.2

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it within ranking alone, because the ranker doesnt know anything about the length of words.

To sphinx words are just numbers, (either crc or a lookup table - depending on dict) so it doesnt know how long the word is.

The only thing I can think that might help is `index_exact_words` which will affect rank on exact word matches. (so rank will rank higher than ranking as its an exact match)

(to clarify is exact_hit is just all query words words match the field words, but knows nothing match morpholoyg or prefix words matching. so "rankng" > "rank" is still an exact_hit, as they are the same word subject to stemming)